# Finding sum of numbers through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I need to calculate the sum of a few numbers that are within a `<td>` tag. However, I end up getting a concatenated string: `513`, instead of `18`.

**HTML**

```
<div class='all'>Sum: </div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
    var sumCell = $(this).find('td');
    if(sumCell.text() != 20) {
        var str = sumCell.text();
        $('.all').append(array_sum(str.split(' ')));
    }
});
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wvwC/24/) where I attempt using `array_sum()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// setting the text of the '.all' element(s):
$('.all').text(function() {
         // selecting all the '<td>' elements,:
  return $('td').map(function() {
    // converting the text to a number:
    var n = parseFloat($(this).text());
    // if the text is not a number, or the text (as a number) is equal to 20
    // we return 0 (effectively not adding the value), otherwise we return the
    // number:
    return (!n || n === 20) ? 0 : n;
  // get() converts that collection to an array,
  // reduce reduces the array to a single value (in this case by adding its
  // components together):
  }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
});
```

```js
$('.all').text(function() {
  return $('td').map(function() {
    var n = parseFloat($(this).text());
    return (!n || n === 20) ? 0 : n;
  }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
});
```

```css
div.all {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

div.all::before {
  content: 'Result: ';
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='all'>Sum:</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
  - [Conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: It is a better approach indeed. But how can I exclude the number "20" from the list? Because `if(sumCell.text() != 20) {}` would not work in this case.

Comment: You don't want to add any cells whose value *is* twenty, or whose value is *twenty or greater*?

Comment: Just `== 20`. Not greater.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/5wvwC/25/

```
var nums = [];
    $('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
        var sumCell = $(this).find('td');
        if(sumCell.text() != 20) {
            var str = sumCell.text();
            nums.push(str);
        }
    });
$('.all').append(array_sum(nums));
```

Your code doesn't work because in each you're adding a single td value. Each iteration takes the value of a single td and appends to .all. You need to take all td values and then add them together.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's complicating things a bit. I would have a sum function that expects numbers. It is up to you to pass in what the function expects:

```
function array_sum(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b
    })
}
```

Then you can grab all numbers into an array:

```
var ns = $('tbody').find('tr td').map(function () {
    return Number($(this).text()); // make sure it's a number
}).toArray();
```

And finally use `array_sum` to add them up and append to the output:

```
$('.all').append(array_sum(ns));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5wvwC/26/